# JavaScript HTTP GET for multiple URLs

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, rss

I'm a beginner with JS and I'm currently trying to create a script to get entries from multiple RSS feeds.

So far I'm successfully able to query all the feeds and get all the entries, but when I try to store them locally to display them, it only shows the last RSS feeds entries (Assuming this is because it re-runs the entire script and doesn't store entires from each HTTP GET).

I've been stuck for hours now trying to get it to store each entry instead of just re-running everything for each url. Does anyone know how I can make it store each entry for each $http.get it runs through so that I can display all entires from all the URLs?

Here is the code I have so far:

```
db.transaction(function(tx) {
          tx.executeSql("SELECT (data) FROM note", [], function(tx,res){
              for(var iii = 0; iii < res.rows.length; iii++){


                  alert(res.rows.item(iii).data);

                  $http.get("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&q=" + res.rows.item(iii).data)
                     .success(function(data) {
                         $scope.rssTitle = data.responseData.feed.title;
                         $scope.rssUrl = data.responseData.feed.feedUrl;
                         $scope.rssSiteUrl = data.responseData.feed.link;
                         $scope.entries = data.responseData.feed.entries;
                         window.localStorage["entries"] = JSON.stringify(data.responseData.feed.entries);
                     })
                     .error(function(data) {
                         console.log("ERROR: " + data);
                         if(window.localStorage["entries"] !== undefined) {
                             $scope.entries = JSON.parse(window.localStorage["entries"]);
                         }
                     });
              }
          });
      }, function(err){
          alert("An error occured while displaying saved notes");
      });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Thing: Don't use WebSQL. It's not a W3C Spezification and only works in Chrome. 
Use and Array to store all your results and then you can use a ng-repeat to display the feeds.

Comment: Makes sense! How could I add a result to an array in this case? I've tried outputting some values but I can't seem to find which correct variable I need to store in the array.

Comment: For performance it is better don't assign the values directly to the scope. If you doing this: `for(var i; i < x.length; i++){$scope.array[] = x[i].value}` Angular will Re-Rendering your DOM everytime where you change a $scope value. Better do this: `for(var i < x.length; i++){array[] = x[i].value} $scope.array = array;` You can assign a value to an array with `array[] = value` or `array.push(value)` But don't forget to define your array as array `array = []` or `array = new Array()`

Answer (score 0):

2nd thing: don't use the [Google Feed API which has been deprecated](https://blog.superfeedr.com/google-feed-api-alternative/)... AND taken down by Google for a couple days as a warning back in December.